# SignaturePadView GetImage throwing OutOfMemoryError excetion

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using SignaturePadView. I want to save signatures as images. I am testing on the sample code provided [here](http://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad).

```
points = signature.Points; 
var image = signature.GetImage(true);
```

I can get the Points but when I call GetImage  java runtime  OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the code for the SignaturePad. It looks like by default the bitmap is too big to fit into memory. I gave it a size and disabled cropping as a workaround.

`var bitmap = signature.GetImage(new SizeF(200,200), false);`